# The Debugging Primaries

Tags: ruby

I'm doing the "[8.1 The Debugging Primaries](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/50-debugging/lessons/119-the-debugging-primaries#)". One of the exercises asks me to:

> fix the method so that it prints the name and age from the parameter I
>   pass to it.

The exercise looks like this:

```
def describe(user_info)
  "My name is #{user_info[0]} and I'm #{user_info[1]} years old."
end
```

there is a hint below the exercise:

> Do a p on the user_info and look at what parameter I'm passing to it.

I wrote the statement `p user_info` and a `@` sign before the parameter in the method:

```
def describe(user_info)
  "My name is #{@user_info[0]} and I'm #{@user_info[1]} years old."
end

p user_info
```

but received an error.

Can anyone tell me how to do to get the positive result and please explain what is the meaning of the square brackets after the parameter?

Comment: i think you were required to do "describe(p)"

Comment: FYI, `p` is just a more debug-friendly version of `puts`.

Comment: you "received error". What error was this? Including all the relevant information can help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in this way:

```
def describe(user_info)
  p "My name is #{user_info["name"]} and I'm #{user_info["age"]} years old."
end
```

Please, read errors =)

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
class: NameError
message: undefined local variable or method `user_info' for main:Object
backtrace: RubyMonk:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

`user_info` is a local variable defined in the scope of method `describe`. As stated in the error message, it is not defined outside the method. Move the instruction `p user_info` inside the method.